# Two vector sequences that are basis of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The sequence of vectors $(u_{1}, \cdots, u_{n})$ form a basis of the vector space $E$.

I need to show that there is a $k \in \{1, \cdots, n \}$ such that $ (u_{1}, \cdots, u_{k-1}, v, u_{k+1}, \cdots, u_{n}) $ is a base of $E$, with $v \in E \setminus \{ 0_{E} \}$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: what I wrote was that $v = b_{1} \cdot u_{1} + \cdots + b_{n} \cdot u_{n}$. 
Now I need to prove somehow that $a_{1} \cdot u_{1} + \cdots + a_{k-1} \cdot u_{k-1} + a_{k} \cdot (b_{1} \cdot u_{1} + \cdots + b_{n} \cdot u_{n}) + a_{k+1} \cdot u_{k+1} + \cdots + a_{n} \cdot u_{n} = a_{1} \cdot u_{1} + \cdots + a_{n} \cdot u_{n}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote in the comments, $v$ can be written as $b_1u_1+b_2u_2+\cdots+b_nu_n$. Choose $k$ such that $b_k\ne0$. Then $u_k$ is a linear combination of $\{u_1,\ldots,u_{k-1},v,u_{k+1}\ldots,u_n\}$. So, since the set$$\{u_1,\ldots,u_{k-1},v,u_{k+1}\ldots,u_n\}\tag1$$spans $V$ and $\dim V=n$, $(1)$ is a basis of $V$.

Comment: Probably you want to add $v$ to the set  $\{u_1,\ldots,u_{k-1},u_{k+1}\ldots,u_n\}$.

Comment: Indeed. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. If $v$ is a linear combination of the elements of the sequence $\{ u_{1}, \cdots, u_{n} \}$ then doesn't it mean that the sequence $\{u_1,\ldots,u_{k-1},v,u_{k+1}\ldots,u_n\}$ is linearly dependent?

Comment: Why? I removed an element from the set and added a new one. Why it should become linearly dependent then?

Comment: If you are adding $v$, and $v$ is a linear combination of the other elements of the set then the set becomes linearly dependent right?

Comment: I've added $v$, yes, but I removed $u_k$ too.

Comment: So $v = u_{k}$ right?

Comment: No. The vector $v$ is the $v$ from the statement of your problem.

Comment: Then I don't really understand how $u_{k}$ is a linear combination of $\{u_{1}, \ldots, u_{k-1}, v, u_{k+1}, \ldots, u_{n} \}$

Comment: If $v=b_1u_1+\cdots+b_kv_k+\cdots+b_nu_n$, then$$u_k=-\frac{b_1}{b_k}u_1-\frac{b_2}{b_k}u_2-\cdots-\frac{b_{k-1}}{b_k}u_{k-1}+\frac1{b_k}v-\frac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}u_{k+1}-\cdots-\frac{b_n}{b_k}u_n.$$

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks